# FoxPro ODBC Table not found

Tags: odbc, visual-foxpro, foxpro

The FoxPro ODBC on my machine is only able to connect to certain tables in the ODBC Connection. When I try to connect to specific tables in the same connection I receive the error [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Not a table.( #123). However, I am successfully connected to other tables without an issue. I know these tables I am unable to connect to aren't corrupted because I am able to view the data in them using Visual Fox Pro.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd use the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver instead of ODBC. It's faster and more fully featured.

Then check whether the TableValidate setting is affecting it. To check that, back up the data then open the table exclusively in Visual FoxPro and issue the following in the command window:

```
append blank
go bottom
delete
pack
```

This will append and then delete a blank record, forcing the header counters to be recalculated. Then try it via the connection.

Also try turning tablevalidate off for the OLE DB driver as follows.

Create a text file called CONFIG.FPW in the same location as vfpoledb.dll, on a 64-bit machine this will be in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB'.

In the text file just put one line:

TABLEVALIDATE=0

And retry.

Comment: Alan, I appreciate the help. I followed this process exactly and I am now receiving an error stating that the driver cannot open the .dbf file to the table. Is this because of a read/write lock? After restarting the computer when trying to open the able again I receive the Not a table. error 123 as I did before.

Answer (score 0):

First: Do not use ODBC driver UNLESS your tables are VFP6 and earlier compatible. The last ODBC driver released was only for 6 and earlier. If you still need to use ODBC then check Sybase ADS driver. It is compatible with later versions too and local mode is for free.les

Second:Be sure that the tables you are trying to open are really not corrupted (not a table error is often occurs when the header info is off by pne record = you can check the details on "Not A table" entry on foxwikis. You might be looking into two different files when you check from VFP and through OLEDB driver. You can specify the fullpath to be sure.